# Unable to host a Service Bus WCF Host in IIS on Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-appfabric

I have worker roles that send out multicast messages using the azure service bus.  Two of the consumers of these messages are websites hosted on Azure.  I know that there are issues hosting [service bus WCF endpoints in IIS](http://www.wadewegner.com/2010/05/host-wcf-services-in-iis-with-service-bus-endpoints/) even when running on premise.  I've followed the [Microsoft's advice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee725240.aspx) and [configured a service host programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706770.aspx).

One of the websites has been using this technique successfully for quite a while.  It uses the hosted web core (it was developed before full IIS was an option on Azure) and it initialises the service host as part of the `RoleEntryPoint.OnRun()`.  I'm trying to move this site to using full IIS.  Because in full IIS the RoleEntryPoint runs in a different process to the site itself and the service host needs access to some static variables in the site I've moved the initialisation of the service host to the `Global.asax` `Application_OnStart`.  This code works fine when running as a website under IIS locally and it runs fine when running in the compute emulator, but once I deploy it to the cloud my WCF host never seems to receive any messages.  I haven't been able to catch any errors that are occurring.

Has anyone else out there successfully deployed something like this?

Comment: Without any information from traces/errorlogs it's difficult to help... When the consumers try to connect to the WCF services they will throw exceptions with further info.. why don't start there with the investigation...

Comment: This is what's killing me, I haven't been able to catch any errors.  I might need a different plan of attack.